# Pre-selecting dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown for hours on my webpage. The backend is returning the value as an int.
eg: "TimeHours":12.

The following code doesn't preset the value to 12. However, if I change the BE value from 12 to "12" it works.

How should I get this to work? I tried changing `<option value="1">1 </option> to <option value=1>1 </option>` and that didn't work too.

```
<li class="align" >                
 <select id="TimeHours" name="TimeHours" 
       style="width:60px" data-value="{{this.TimeHours}}">                    
       <option value="1">1 </option>
       <option value="2">2 </option>
       <option value="3">3 </option>
       <option value="4">4 </option>
       <option value="5">5 </option>
       <option value="6">6 </option>
       <option value="7">7 </option>
       <option value="8">8 </option>
       <option value="9">9 </option>
       <option value="10">10 </option>
       <option value="11">11 </option>
       <option value="12">12 </option>                       
  </select></li>
```

Comment: Why aren't you simply setting the correct option to `selected` when you send the page? That way you don't need a `data-value` attribute, or any client–side scripting, and it will work in every browser that ever supported forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery `.val` function..

```
$('#TimeHours').val(function () {
    return $(this).data('value')['TimeHours'];
});
```

Assuming `data-value='{"TimeHours": "12"}'`

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ts594/

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function(){
  var select = $("#TimeHours");
  select.val(select.attr("data-value"));
});
```

Using `.attr()` returns a string, as opposed to `.data()` which converts the value to type.

Comment: I don't think it matter what type you pass to `val()`.

Comment: Can you give us the rendered HTML of `{{this.TimeHours}}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Mark the one you want to be selected as selected this way:

```
   <option value="2">2 </option>
   <option value="3">3 </option>
   <option value="4">4 </option>
   <option value="5">5 </option>                    
  ...
   <option selected value="12">12 </option>
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the obvious answer. Probably get down–voted though because it doesn't require any script at all. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
data-value="{{praseInt(this.TimeHours)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than adding `selected` to the correct `<option>` tag, there is no way to pre-select an option.

That's why I have this code:

```
(function() {
    // enable default attribute on <select>
    var sels = document.querySelectorAll("select[data-value]"), l = sels.length, i,
        opts, m, j;
    for( i=l-1; i>=0; i--) {
        opts = sels[i].getElementsByTagName('option'); m = opts.length;
        for( j=0; j<m; j++) {
            if( opts[j].value == sels[i].getAttribute("data-value")) {
                sels[i].selectedIndex = j;
                break;
            }
        }
        sels[i].removeAttribute("data-value");
    }
})();
```

Comment: Not sure about that first sentence, an option can be made selected by setting its `selected` attribute (to make it the default selected option) or property (to make it the currently selected option) using script. But setting the correct option  to selected in the markup is the obvious solution.

Comment: This is insanely overly complicated. Adding selected to the option is the best, easiest, and correct way to do it.

Comment: @saml But it's a pain to have to add a check on every single option tag to see if it's the right one. This just dynamic-ises it.